# ruby JSON.parse fails on decimal numbers with point but without fractions

Tags: json, ruby, parsing, decimal, point

I have a json string like this :

```
{"weight": 56.}
```

I can enter this string into NodeJS interpreter and get a parsed hash as a result:

```
$ js
> {"Weight":56.}
{ Weight: 56 }
> {"Weight":56}
{ Weight: 56 }
```

as you see, NodeJS accepts both inputs with identical result

But in Ruby, for the same string I get

> JSON::ParserError: ... unexpected token

until I remove '.' after the number

sample session :

```
irb...> s='{"Weight":56.}'
=> "{\"Weight\":56.}"
irb...> JSON.parse(s)
JSON::ParserError: 784: unexpected token at '{"Weight":56.}'
```

...

```
irb...> s='{"Weight":56}'
=> "{\"Weight\":56}"
irb...> JSON.parse(s)
=> {"Weight"=>56}
```

Can anything be done to Ruby JSON library to improve its conformance to JS ?

Now I have to filter these stray dec.points by regular expressions before parsing them as JSON

Comment: According to the JSON specification, `56.` is an invalid number: a `.` must be followed by a digit.

Comment: 56. is supported at least by C and Fortran. So it is not surprising that NodeJS(v8) supports it as well. In Ruby this is problematic as there could be a method call after the point, like 56.abs. But what JSON.parse expects as its input, is JSON, not Ruby code

Comment: _"what JSON.parse expects as its input, is JSON"_ – yes, exactly. It expects JSON, not C or Fortran or JavaScript. And `56.` is not valid in JSON, whether or not it may be valid syntax in other languages.